# How to allow only few people to login into Azure Web App using AAD?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app in Azure Cloud. I know, I can add authentication/Authorization to this web app using Azure AD. But that will allow every user registered in that AAD to access the Web app. What I want is, only a handful of people are allowed to access this web app using Azure AD login screen.

Comment: Hi, Does this help you?

Comment: @Card Zhao I am yet to test it. I am facing problem in registering my web app in AAD though option given in Authorization/Authentication. May be I don't have permission for new App Registration in AAD.

Comment: If you are in a user role, you need to request the administrator to log in to the Azure portal and set `Users can register applications` to `yes`. see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLYhg.png

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to restrict the Azure AD application to a set of users in the Azure AD tenant.

See:[Restrict your Azure AD app to a set of users in an Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users).